# How to get consecutive pairs of words in Perl

Tags: perl, split

With this sentence:

```
my $sent = "Mapping and quantifying mammalian transcriptomes RNA-Seq";
```

We want to get all possible consecutive pairs of words.

```
my $var = ['Mapping and',
           'and quantifying',
           'quantifying mammalian',
           'mammalian transcriptomes',
           'transcriptomes RNA-Seq'];
```

Is there a compact way to do it?

Comment: Answers vary in whether they keep the original whitespace between words or just use a space.  Which did you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
my $sent = "Mapping and quantifying mammalian transcriptomes RNA-Seq";
my @pairs = $sent =~ /(?=(\S+\s+\S+))\S+/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
my @sent = split(/\s+/, $sent);
my @var = map { $sent[$_] . ' ' . $sent[$_ + 1] } 0 .. $#sent - 1;
```

i.e. just split the original string into an array of words, and then use `map` to iteratively produce the desired pairs.

Answer (score 2):

A variation that (perhaps unwisely) relies on operator evaluation order but doesn't rely on fancy regexes or indices:

```
my @words = split /\s+/, $sent;
my $last = shift @words;
my @var;
push @var, $last . ' ' . ($last = $_) for @words;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have it as a single line, but the following code should give you somewhere to start. Basically does it with a `push` and a regext with `/g`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my $t1 = 'aa bb cc dd ee ff';
my $t2 = 'aa bb cc dd ee';

foreach my $txt ( $t1, $t2 )
{
    my @a;
    push( @a, $& ) while( $txt =~ /\G\S+(\s+\S+|)\s*/g );
    print Dumper( \@a );
}
```

One liner thanks to the syntax from @ysth

```
 my @a = $txt =~ /\G(\S+(?:\s+\S+|))\s*/g;
```

My regex is slightly different in that if you have an odd number of words, the last word still gets an entry.